# The joint pdf of two random variables defined as functions of two iid chi-square

Tags: probability, self-study

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two i.i.d.
chi-square distributed random variables with four degrees of freedom.
How can we get the joint probability distribution function of the random variables  $U=(X-Y)/(X+Y)$, $V=X+Y$?

Comment: What is the parameter $\alpha$? The chi-squared distribution has only one parameter, the degrees of freedom.

Comment: I expect in this case you're meant to do a bivariate change of variable. Don't forget the Jacobian.

Comment: Note that $V = X+Y$, being the sum of i.i.d. $\chi^2$ random variables with $4$ degrees of freedom, is itself a $\chi^2$ random variable with $8$ degrees of freedom.
Since $X$ and $Y$ are nonnegative random variables, we note that for any $\beta > 0$, _conditioned_ on
$V = X+Y = \beta$, $X-Y$ can take on values in $[-\beta,+\beta]$. Thus, $U = \frac{X-Y}{X+Y}$ takes on values in
$[-1,+1]$, and this holds true regardless of the choice of positive number $\beta$.  This hints at the possibility that $U$ and $V$ might be independent random variables (as is indeed shown in wolfie's answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to do this manually, just look up the *Method of Transformations* in a good book on mathematical statistics. For ease of computation, I prefer to use automated tools, where they are available. In this instance, $X$ and $Y$ are independent $Chisquared(n)$ random variables, so the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$, say $f(x,y)$ is:

[image]

Then, the joint pdf of $(U = \frac{X-Y}{X+Y}, V=X+Y)$ is say $g(u,v)$:

[image]

where `Transform` is an automated function (from the `mathStatica` add-on to *Mathematica*) that does the nitty gritties of the Method of Transformations for one (I am one of the authors of the package), and with domain of support:

[image]

All done.

Here is a plot of the joint pdf $g(u,v)$ in your case, with parameter $n=4$:

[image]

Comment: It is interesting to see that $U$ and $V$ turn out to be independent random variables. $V$ is, of course, a $\chi^2$ random variable, while $U$ is a centered and scaled Beta random variable? Perhaps this latter too can be deduced directly?